# How to display a video popup in front of all other dom tree elements?

Tags: jquery, dom, video, slider

I wanted to display a video popup over my slider. But now there is a z-index problem. The video was behind the image of the slider. After adding `movie.css( "zIndex", 2147483647 );` in the jQuery-code the video was in front of the slider image in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Besides that the controls didnt work. Even with adding the controls with jquery `movie.prop("controls",true);` you only could see the control, there were also some hover effects but you couldnt press any button. With video controls ="true" there was even a browser crash in chrome.

I was looking on the internet and found some stuff about shadow dom trees but still I dont know how to get it to work. I know that you can select the video controls in css with `::-webkit-media-controls` but since the Chrome browser crashed and firefox is no webkit browser I couldnt test it. Unfortunately I dont know how to select the firefox video control attribute. There is no  `::-moz-media-controls`.

I'm not able to post all of my code but I hope this will be enough to receive some help:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        // show popup when you click on the link
        var movie = $('#movie');
        $('#clips li').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var pdf_id = $(this).attr('class');
            var clip_id = $(this).children().attr('id');
            for (var i = 0; i < topkeys.length; i++) { 
                if (pdf_id == topkeys[i]) {                    
                    var lowerkeys = $.map(pdf_videos[i], function (n) {
                        return Object.keys(n); 
                    });
                    for (var j = 0; j < lowerkeys.length; j++) {

                        if (clip_id == lowerkeys[j]) {                            
                            var thumbnail = pdf_videos[i][pdf_id][clip_id]['mainthumbnail'];
                            var mp4url = pdf_videos[i][pdf_id][clip_id]['mp4url'];
                            var webmurl = pdf_videos[i][pdf_id][clip_id]['webmurl'];                            
                            $("#movie").attr('poster', thumbnail);                            
                            $("#mp4").attr('src', mp4url);
                            $("#webm").attr('src', webmurl);
                            var movie = $('#movie');                            
                            $('.overlay-bg').show();                             
                            movie.get(0);
                            movie.load();
                            movie.prop("controls",true); 
                            //movie.css( "zIndex", 2147483647 );                        

                        }
                    }
                }
            }



        });        


        if (movie[0].paused) {
            $('.pause-btn').hide();
        };                 


        // hide popup when user clicks on close button
        $('.close-btn').click(function () {
            $('.overlay-bg').hide(); // hide the overlay
            movie[0].pause();
        });     



        $('.play-btn').click(function () {
            movie[0].play();  //Select a DOM ELEMENT!
            $('.pause-btn').show();
            $('.play-btn').hide();
            $("#movie").mouseleave(function() {
                $('.pause-btn').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            });
            $("#movie").mouseenter(function() {
                $(".pause-btn").show();
            });           


        });


        $('.pause-btn').click(function () {
            movie[0].play();  //Select a DOM ELEMENT!
            $('.pause-btn').hide();
            $('.play-btn').show();
        });

        if (movie[0].paused) {
            $('.pause-btn').hide();
        };

        if (!movie[0].paused) {

            $("#movie").mouseenter(function() {
                $(".pause-btn").show();
            }).mouseleave(function() {
                $('.pause-btn').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            });
        }

        $('.pause-btn').click(function () {
            movie[0].pause();  //Select a DOM ELEMENT!
        });

        // hides the popup if user clicks anywhere outside the container
        $('.overlay-bg').click(function () {
            $('.overlay-bg').hide();
            movie[0].pause();
        })
        // prevents the overlay from closing if user clicks inside the popup overlay
        $('#clip_id').click(function () {
            return false;
        }); 

    });
```

What this code does: 
You see images in the slider, there are several presentations with images (all list elements with the images of one presentation have the same id). Below the slider there are video thumbnails (which and how much depending on the list element id of the current slide element). If you click on the thumbnail the video popup is displayed. But then the frustrating part begins - you cant access the controls or the video is behind the slide element. So how to prevent that?

P.S.: I'm using the bx slider as image slider.

HTML:

```
<div class="overlay-bg">
    <div id="videowrapper">
        <div id="wrapper2">
            <div id="left-column2">
                <div id="clip_id" class="clip">
                    <video  id="movie"  poster="http://url.jpg">
                    <source id="mp4" type="video/mp4" src="http://url.mp4"></source>
                    <source id="webm" type="video/webm" src="http://url.webm"></source>
                    </video>
                    <button class="close-btn">X</button>
                    <button class="play-btn">▶</button>
                    <button class="pause-btn">II</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end wrapper2 -->
    </div><!-- end videowrapper -->
</div> <!-- end overlay-bg -->
```

CSS:

```
#left-column2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 260px;
    width:632px; 
    height: 320px;

}

#wrapper2 {
    width: 1012px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

 .clip video {    
    width: 568px;
    /*height: 320px; new height*/
    height: 426px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 32px;
    top: 0px; 

    }

#overlay {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 32px;
     width: 568px;
     /*height: 320px; new height*/
     height: 426px;
     background-color: #000;    
     z-index: 9999;
     }

 #overlay video {
     width: 568px;
     /*height: 320px; new height*/
    height: 426px;
 }

 #close_button {
     z-index: 10000;
     position: absolute;
     top: 90px;
     right: 32px;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     color: #fff;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 20px;
     cursor: pointer;
 } 

    .overlay-bg {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;    
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #000; /* fallback */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
} 


    .close-btn {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        top: 30px;
        right: 0px;
    }

    .play-btn {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        top: 210px;
        left: 285px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .pause-btn {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        top: 210px !important;
        left: 285px;
        opacity: 0.7; 
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;      
    }
    .close-btn:hover {
        background: #05abe0;
    }

    .play-btn:hover {
        background: #05abe0;
    } 

    .pause-btn:hover {
        background: #05abe0;
    } 
#movie {
    z-index: 2147483646 !important;
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important;
}
```

Comment: What `display:` type is your video popup? It really needs to be `block` & have `position: relative` to make it work as you seek

Comment: Thx Rich, i tried but it didnt work. :(  I couldnt find how to select the media control in css. Maybe with a higher z-index it would work. The search goes on ... ;)

Comment: Can you post your CSS and HTML for the pop-over? It may help

Comment: Alright I edited it - for css and html code please look in the question.